# Android parse: Get strings from parsequeryadapter and store them into an ArrayList

Tags: java, android, string, parse-platform, parse-android-sdk

I have a ParseQueryAdapter class, and my items are being retrieved successfully.
However, if I have this for loop to view the objects (strings):

```
 for (int i =0;i<adapter.getCount();i++){
        Log.d("Ab", adapter.getItem(i).toString());
    }
```

I get these:

```
   com.example.ab_me.example.classname@41ef11f8    
   com.example.ab_me.example.classname@41ef33d8
   com.example.ab_me.example.classname@41ef40c0
```

**Note**: *For security reasons, I replaced my app name with `example` and my classname with `classname`.*
Why is this? It is supposed to be:

```
listItem1
listItem2
listItem3
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Object` that is returned from `getItem` method call does not override `toString()` method, so java uses a default implementation in this case because it doesn't 'know' how to convert the object to a `String` type.

If you own this type, simply `@Override` the `toString()` method with your own implementation.

*Example*:

Assuming your type name is `YourType`. I mean, `adapter.getItem(i)` returns an object of `YourType`. In `YourType.java`:

```
class YourType {
    private String exampleField1;
    private String exampleField2;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return exampleField1 + ", " + exampleField2;
    }
}
```

Comment: Give an example please? Sorry I'm new

Comment: Wait nevermind my deleted comments. Ok. what is exampleField1, how do I define it?

Comment: In your case the type is  `com.example.ab_me.example.classname`. I have no idea what fields you have in this class.. Just override a toString method in your classname and provide your own implementation to let java know how to covert your classname object to String. In my case I have 2 example field just to show how the implementation might look like. You don't have to define those.